# Batch wait until Windows 10 copy finished

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch program for work that renames files in a certain way. ("Test" -> "year-month-day-test-person abbreviation")

To make the workday easier I want to make the whole thing as uncomplicated as possible for the user.

So my idea was that the user only has to copy the files with ctrl+x to the clipboard and then activate a shortcut via the taskbar.
Now a normal file folder opens and inserts the files into this folder by starting a VBS script (ctrl+V).

Now I have the progblem that I can not determine how long windows needs to move the files into the directory, because it is not executed via a batch "copy" but via ctrl+X and ctrl+V.

I tried to get the information from the explorer process, but this did not work.

I even tried to get the information from the CPU usage but this is also very difficult.

The goal is to simply copy the files from a unknown directory to a directory where they can be renamed.

I attach you my small script as an explanation.

I have already tried to solve this by counting the files. However, it can take longer than 1 seconds until a single file was transferred, which makes the sytsem invalid.

```
@Echo Off >nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion >nul
chcp 65001 >nul



set Kuerzel=fb

del /q "Temp\"

start "" "Temp"
timeout /t 1
start "" "data\strg+v.vbs"



::wait until all files are there
:loobt

    set dateien1=0
    for /F %%i in ('dir Temp\* /B /A-d') do set /A dateien1=dateien1+1

    timeout /t 1

    set dateien2=0
    for /F %%i in ('dir Temp\* /B /A-d') do set /A dateien2=dateien2+1

if not %dateien1% == %dateien2% goto loobt
if %dateien1% == 0 goto loobt



::rename

for /r "Temp\" %%i in (*.*) do (
    set "neu=%%~ni"
    ren "%%i" "%date:~6%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-!neu:_=-!-%Kuerzel%%%~xi"
)

timeout /t 2

start "" "data\strg+a.vbs"
start "" "data\strg+c.vbs"
timeout /t 1
start "" "data\alt+F4.vbs"
```

I apologize for any incorrect grammar or confusing words. I have given my best to formulate an  understandable text in English.

Comment: Don't use the `START` command to run the `VBS`.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could explain the purpose of changing to codepage 65001, because you don't appear to have used any characters which are not in almost every standard default codepage. It may also be beneficial we were to know the purpose, and preferable the content of `strg+v.vbs`, `strg+a.vbs`, `strg+c.vbs`, and `alt+F4.vbs` too.

Comment: I'm assuming that for some inexplicable reason that you've decided to create separate vbscript files to perform GUI keystrokes via `sendkeys`, `[CTRL]`+`[V]` to paste unknown data from the clipboard into the 'explorer' window opened via `start "" "Temp"`; then later `[CTRL]`+`[A]`, `[CTRL]`+`[C]`, and `[CTRL]`+`[F4]`, in sequence to hopefully select all, copy, then close that particular currently open 'explorer' window. What we therefore need is an explanation as to why you're trying to do this via the GUI, and exactly what is happening or not happening according to your code's intent.

Comment: @Compo I change the codepage in each of my programs. Simply so that I don't have to worry about letters like "üäö". I know this can lead to problems but so far I haven't had any. But it's true I could just leave it out of the code in that case. Here is one of my VBS scripts:
````
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "notepad"
WshShell.SendKeys ("^c") 
````

The scripts are all built in the same way. I know that this is not the best or most efficient solution. However, this was only for testing

Comment: @Florian, the letters `ü`, `ä`, and `ö` which you've specifically used for your comment are not Unicode or UTF-8 characters, they are Latin characters available in more than one codepage, I would suggest that you probably wouldn't go far wrong using `1252`